# How to set Font from String in Java

Tags: java, swing, fonts, content-management-system, string-parsing

I have an CMS application which is written using C#, and I should Save FONT's as VARCHAR in a Database. Then I should get the specified FONT from a Java Application.

So how is possible to set a Font to a `JLabel` or a `Font` Object using `String`.

For example, I have a String which Contains Font Type, Size and Name:

```
Type:Bold Size:12 Name:Microsoft Sans Serif
```

So how should I convert the typed String to `Font` in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
JLabel.setFont(Font.decode("fontname-style-pointsize"))
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: You wrote derivate - typo? :D

Comment: Interesting. But what is a bit frustrating is that there is no `encode` to go with the `decode`.